# Receive 403 Forbidden error when calling ProjectResource.Create, but project still created

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-apps-script-api

When I use the Debug Console to execute C#/.NET code to create a new project (`ProjectResource.Create(...)`), I receive a "403 Forbidden" error. However, I still receive a `Project` response and the API correctly creates a file in my Drive. Because Google does not expose what is happening under their API, I have no idea why I see that message in the Debug Console. No errors propagate to the runtime, and I have a strange feeling this is an erroneous output error message left from production.

Why is this happening, and can I remove / prevent this error?

---

Code:

```
var cpr = new CreateProjectRequest
{
     Title = name
};
scriptID = projectResource.Create(cpr).Execute().ScriptId;
```

Error:

> The caller does not have permission

Error object:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The caller does not have permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[The caller does not have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

---

An alternative possibility might be an issue with the way I set up my Google Console Cloud, but considering the functionality is still intact, I cannot help but think I did it correctly. Furthermore, my credential authorizations all succeed without error.

I authorize my services in the following way:

```
 scriptService = new ScriptService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
         ApiKey = apiKeyUser,
         HttpClientInitializer = credential,
         ApplicationName = applicationName
    });
 projectResource = new ProjectsResource(scriptService);
```

My API key is set up to function with both the Apps Script API and Drive API.
My OAuth Client ID is of `type: other` (it's the only way for desktop applications).

Any thoughts?

PS In my efforts I tried using the `DriveService` to do the same thing. I still receive the same error in Debug, and alas it still works just like above.

```
File body = new File()
{
    MimeType = "google-apps.script",
    Name = name,
};

var test = driveService.Files.Create(body);

test.Fields = "id";
var f = test.Execute();
```

Comment: Not enough info to go on, you're going to get just opinions (if that).

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for letting me know. I've added more context.

Comment: Consider expanding on your statement "the way I set up my Google Console Cloud"

Comment: I have you tried using this library https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet?